# Attach S3 bucket to URL endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3

How can I attach an S3 bucket to an URL on my site. I tried but could not get it to work.

For instance my URL is:

```
mysite.com/media
```

And my S3 bucket should be linked directly to the above URL?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use CloudFront in front of S3. This will allow you to use your domain and serve content from S3.

Check out [Using CloudFront with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html) for details on how to do it.